# Will scala work with JDK 1.10

Tags: java, scala

The scala download page says that you have to have JDK 1.8 installed.  It doesn't say anything about newer versions of the JDK.

Does scala work with JDK 1.10?

Answer (score 4):

A page was recently added to the official Scala website outlining the compatibility of Scala versions with different JDK versions: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

In short: JDK 8 is recommended. However compiling and running recent Scala versions should work on JDK 9 and 10, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility of encountering some corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

The JDK has a fairly good track record of backwards compatibility.

Unfortunately, there are always some things that change. Even from minor version to minor version you can find something broken.

I can guarantee there will be *something* that doesn't work, but in general most of the core features will. Still, I would never trust any change on production until you've tested it thoroughly.

Look forward to doing such testing every 6 months now.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue. On Ubuntu 16.04 I had installed JDK 10 and then installed scala 2.11.6.

Using IntelliJ IDE I was able to make them work together however in terminal when typing

```
$ scala
```

I got just

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/Compilable`

The solution was to install also JDK 8 and set it to be used by default, that is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

and to choose JDK 8. After that, everything is fine :)

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```